# Nested amsmath environments with \newenvironment

Tags: environments, amsmath

Using the `amsmath` environment, I'd like to create a short-cut for

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    ...
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

But saying

```
\newenvironment{eqs}
  {\begin{equation*}\begin{split}}
  {\end{split}\end{equation*}}
```

and using it with

```
\begin{eqs}
  ...
\end{eqs}
```

produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{split} on input line 67 ended by \end{eqs}.
```

However, using `\newcommand` works — but `\eqs{...}` over several lines looks a bit weird:

```
\newcommand{\eqs}[1]{
  {\begin{equation*}\begin{split}{#1}\end{split}\end{equation*}}}

% ...

\eqs{
  ...
  ...}
```

Is it possible to get this to work with a new environment, or are there better ways to achieve something equivalent?

Comment: Isn't it as simple to use the `align*`environment?

Comment: For this particular problem, you're absolutely right! But I was interested in the general solution anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) processes some environments multiple times in order to perform measuring. As such, it *captures* the environment contents using TeX "parameter text" approach. This requires an explicitly visible `\end{<env>}` that accompanies a `\begin{<env>}`. In your case, you want to forgo this using a different shorthand, making `\end{<env>}` invisible.

One work-around is to capture the body of `eqs` yourself and passing this to the specified environments. [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) provides a means to do this:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{eqs}
  {\begin{equation*}
     \begin{split}
       \BODY
     \end{split}
   \end{equation*}}
```

Answer (score 10):

I prefer using the original form

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   <content>
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

since it is more clear code. However, if you insist, you may use `environ` package as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{eqs}{%
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   \BODY
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
  }
  \begin{document}
    \begin{eqs}
      x &+ y \\
      a &+ b
    \end{eqs}
  \end{document}
```