# \newenvironment as a shortcut

Tags: align, environments

I'm trying to shorten the environment

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
         %equation
     \end{aligned}
 \end{align}
```

by using the \newenvironment command as follows

```
\newenvironment{eqq}
    {\begin{align}\begin{aligned}}
    {\end{aligned}\end{align}}
```

But when I use this new environment like

```
\begin{eqq}
    %equation
\end{eqq}
```

it gives me a bunch of error messages:

> ! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.\par
>
> ! Missing $ inserted.$
>
> ! Missing \endgroup inserted.\endgroup
>
> ! Display math should end with $$.\par
>
> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{align} on input line 163 ended by
>   \end{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for
>   explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{document}

I used \equation instead of \align, but this gives me a weird indent within the pdf.

Comment: Related: [Automatically replace environment `align` by `equation`+`aligned` combination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270337/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Nested `amsmath` environments with `\newenvironment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271712/5764)

Comment: Solution: Use [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/) with `\NewEnviron{eqq}{ \begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
      \BODY
    \end{aligned}
  \end{align}
}`. Full [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/twGC1am8); output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbUVq.png).